# Is it worldwide standard that incoming phone call numbers can be faked?

Tags: phone

I am living in Germany and here attackers can fake the incoming phone number when you get a phone call.

For example you can get a call from 110 (police telephone number) although it is not the police calling you.

I know a person who got a call from his bank's phone number although it wasn't really his bank who was calling.

Is this normal worldwide or is this only a problem in Germany?

Comment: It's a worldwide problem, although it sounds like it's being particularly actively exploited in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **spoofing([wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID_spoofing))** The problem is more or less global, but it also depends on the service provider's infrastructure and their setup and configuration choices.

Service providers would previously just have to choose the lesser out of two evils. Either trust and forward caller ID with all calls from other providers **or** forward calls without caller ID as **unknown number** for all those calls instead.

Several service providers in some European countries are currently in talks to help each other out by mutually agreeing to verify and/or limit which caller IDs they forward to each other.